# React-Starterify Project on Windows computer, babel not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gulp, babeljs

I've just recently started to learn how to use the React framework and have been following the LevelUpTuts channel on youtube. In video 7 of their React playlist, they use this (I guess boilerplate) project called React-Starterify. He made it look easy installing it on his Mac, however I'm on windows and it is becoming a complete nightmare. Here is the project:
https://github.com/Granze/react-starterify

I've followed the exact steps, however when I do the whole "npm run watch".

```
> react-starterify@2.1.3 watch K:\IT Projects\ReactTutes\MailingList\react-starterify-2.1.4
> gulp watch

[13:40:11] Requiring external module babel-core/register
K:\IT Projects\ReactTutes\MailingList\react-starterify-2.1.4\gulpfile.babel.js:108
var opts = Object.assign({}, _watchify2.default.args, customOpts);
                  ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (gulpfile.babel.js:39:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at loader (K:\IT Projects\ReactTutes\MailingList\react-starterify-2.1.4\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:130:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (K:\IT Projects\ReactTutes\MailingList\react-starterify-2.1.4\node_modules\babe
       l-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:140:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (K:\IT Projects\ReactTutes\MailingList\react-starterify-2.1.4\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (K:\IT Projects\ReactTutes\MailingList\react-starterify-2.1.4\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:192:16)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! react-starterify@2.1.3 watch: `gulp watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-starterify@2.1.3 watch script 'gulp watch'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the react-starterify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp watch
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls react-starterify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! K:\IT Projects\ReactTutes\MailingList\react-starterify-2.1.4\npm-debug.log
```

I've tried updating gulp and babel, with the same results.
Gulp CLI and Local versions are 3.9.0.

I looks like it's complaining about something with Windows. Has anyone had any luck getting their Windows machine working with the project?

If not, can anyone recomment another starter project for React, for beginners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used react-starterify, but I have used a site called http://www.overreact.io/ It allows you to draw out your components and then download all of your starter files including a server/gulp. I know for windows you would have to download the zip file, since the npm package doesn't work at the moment, but I have used the zip and it works. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Overract works except for a few issues with the gulp file not exiting after its finished the task. But at least its working. Cheers!

Comment: I read through the Gulp file that is provided. It uses watchify - so that if you change any of your react files, it should automatically rebundle for you. So if you change App.js and save, your terminal should show "Updated #ms" if you leave the Gulp task running.

Comment: On Windows, it gets stuck on both the; >npm run task , > npm start. I imagine that npm run task should not get stuck or is that normal?

Comment: hmmm does it say 'finished default ...' and then seems to hang? I believe that is watchify running if it is doing that. You could always kill the gulp task after it starts to hang and then start up the server since Gulp will be done building the required files.